# Handling the "IndexError: string index out of range" error

Tags: python

I have the following string `my_string`:

```
my_string = 'A15B27C32D72A7B14C9D31'
```

I split this string into `chunks` by the character `A`:

```
chunks = ['A' + elem for elem in my_string.split('A') if elem != '']

chunks
['A15B27C32D72', 'A7B14C9D31']
```

I'd like to be able to check whether there is a number associated with the "D" character of each chunk.  To do this, I use:

```
for elem in chunks:
    if elem[elem.find('D') + 1].isdigit() is False: 
        print('no number associated with D')
    else:
        print('the number associated with D is', elem[elem.find('D') +1])
```

(Technically, this isn't correct since it won't catch cases whereby the number isn't a single digit.)

Now, let's change `my_string` to:

```
my_string = 'A15B27C32DA7B14C9D31'

chunks = ['A' + elem for elem in my_string.split('A') if elem != '']
chunks
['A15B27C32D', 'A7B14C9D31']
```

(notice that `D` in the first chunk doesn't have an associated number)

If I run the following:

```
for elem in chunks:
    if elem[elem.find('D') + 1].isdigit() is False: 
        print('no number associated with D')
    else:
        print('the number associated with D is', elem[elem.find('D') +1])
```

I get:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8844/1838165888.py in <module>
      1 for elem in chunks:
----> 2     if elem[elem.find('D') + 1].isdigit() is False:
      3         print('no number associated with D')
      4     else:
      5         print('the number associated with D is', elem[elem.find('D') +1])

IndexError: string index out of range
```

To fix this, I can use `try`/`except`.

I can also use the following:

```
for elem in chunks:
    if elem[-1].isdigit() is False: 
        print('no number associated with D')
    else:
        print('the number associated with D is', elem[elem.find('D') +1])

no number associated with D
the number associated with D is 3
```

But, both of these approaches feel somewhat hacky.

Is there a more elegant and idiomatic way to handle the `string index out of range` error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest regex for this, but logic-wise, sometimes edge cases just have to be handled by you

```
for elem in chunks:
    first_d = elem.find('D')
    if first_d < len(elem) and elem[first_d + 1].isdigit() is False: 
        print('no number associated with D')
    else:
        print('the number associated with D is', elem[first_d +1])
```

Or, you can tweak the logic a bit

```
for elem in chunks:
    # should only looks for 'D' from start to second-to-last characters
    # because if last character is 'D' it is still not valid
    first_d = elem[:-1].find('D')
    if elem[first_d + 1].isdigit() is False: 
        print('no number associated with D')
    else:
        print('the number associated with D is', elem[first_d + 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `split` again with an `int` conversion inside a `try/except` to validate that the thing after the `D` is a number.

```
>>> my_string = 'A15B27C32D72A7B14C9D31'
>>> for elem in filter(bool, my_string.split("A")):
...     try:
...         print(f"the number associated with D is {int(elem.split('D')[-1])}")
...     except ValueError:
...         print("no number associated with D")
...
the number associated with D is 72
the number associated with D is 31
```

Comment: If question explanation is correct expected numbers should be `7` and `3`

Comment: OP said: *(Technically, this isn't correct since it won't catch cases whereby the number isn't a single digit.)*, which suggests that they wanted to get the full two-digit numbers but didn't know how.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
my_string = 'A15B27C32DA7B14C9D31'
chunk = ['A' + elem for elem in s.split('A') if elem != '']

for elem in chunk:
    num = elem[(elem.find('D') + 1):]
    
    if num == '' or not num.isdigit():
        print('no number associated with D')
    else:
        print('the number associated with D is', num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is 4 problems in your code:

1. If string is `'1234'` → `'1234'.find('D')` will return `-1` and `'1234'[-1+1]` will return `1`. And that is not correct
2. If string is `'123D'` → `'123D'.find('D')` will return `3` and that is last element of list, so `'123D'[3+1]` raises `index out of range` error
3. if string is `''` → `''.find('D')` will return `-1` → `''[-1+1]` → see ②
4. If string is `'D12D34'` → only first `D` will be found. But as I can understand only one `D` should be present in chunk by design

Most closer solution will be:

```
d_index = elem.find('D') + 1
if d_index > 0 and len(elem) > d_index and elem[d_index].isdigit() is True:
    print('the number associated with D is', elem[elem.find('D') +1])
else:
    print('no number associated with D')
```